# How to assign domain name to my Golang server?

Tags: go, webserver, domain-name, namecheap

This might be a very basic question but I've been stucked for 2 days

I've bought the domain name AAA.xyz on Namecheap and I have my Golang web server running on my port :8095 (I've redirected my ports on my router so my server is accessible from everywhere with my public IP http://93.6.XXX.YYY:8095/)

How do I make my Namecheap domain name point to my IP adress with the right port so when I enter AAA.xyz on my browser I get response from my API ?

Comment: You cannot change the default port for HTTP via DNS. There are SRV records that theoretically do it, but those records are not considered by most software (including web browsers). If you don't specify a port in the URL clients will always connect to port 80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to edit your namecheap DNS settings to add an A Record, which will point to your server IP. That's enough to divert all traffic to your domain, to your server.

Although, unless it's not a production setup, it'd be better to let a reverse proxy server like nginx handle the incoming http traffic. Then you won't have to expose your port to the outside world either. (Unless you want to).

Install nginx. Add a proxy pass to your nginx config file which will route all requests coming to port 8095 to your application at 127.0.0.1:8095.

This will also help you when you have multiple go apps running on your server on different ports. You can use different URLs to point to different apps.

e.g.  https://yourdomain.com/app1 will go to 127.0.0.1:8095 
and https://yourdomain.com/app2 will go to 127.0.0.1:8096

Bonus: You can use Letsencrypt to provide your nginx server with an HTTPS certificate for free and then all communication with your applications will be happening through port 443 on HTTPS, without configuring every app to handle the certificate.

Also, open ports 80 and 443 in your firewall.

If you need any help with a specific step. I'll expand on that.